# Converting Numbers Using Dot to Numbers Without Dot - Python

Tags: python

**Simple question:**

**Convert** 0.00072686656200627627 to 72686656200627627

**Convert** 123.00072686656200627627 to 12300072686656200627627

Comment: Convert in which language, logic or what?

Comment: @khelwood: OP presumably means decimal separator. ([In many non-English-speaking countries in Europe and the ME, comma is used to denote the decimal separator](https://www.smartickmethod.com/blog/math/learning-resources/decimal-separators/))

Comment: Those aren’t the same numbers though? It isn’t clear what exactly you’re asking, nor what the type of those “numbers” is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int(str(x).replace('.',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is convert the number to a string, delete the poing, and then convert it again to a numerical value:

```
x = 0.00072686656200627627

# String
x_str = str(x)

# Delete the point
x_str = x_str.replace('.','')

# Integer
x_new = int(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like removing extra zero and removing '.'

`str(x).replace('.','').strip()`

strip will remove trailing zeros

Comment: cast to `int` will strip the zeros. you are trying to strip of an `int`